# How to mute the phone ringtone using cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there any plugin in cordova to change the devices profiles, ie. from silent to ringing or from ringing to vibration and so on.

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS. I don't know about android.

Comment: hmm..thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audio-mode

Install it through cordova CLI by using the following command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-audio-mode
```

You can change your audio profile to 'vibrate', 'normal' or 'silent' by using the following function.

```
audio_mode.change_audio_mode("vibrate", function(success){},function(err){});
```

its not working in emulator run it on device.
this plugin is only in android platform.